# tesnorflow.js "info.backend.decComplexRef is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, machine-learning, face-detection, tensorflow.js

Building a simple application with react to create a 3d parallax effect by tracking user's face using facemesh and three.js
Initially the program logged the expected facemesh data. But suddenly it started showing the following error message

```
info.backend.decComplexRef is not a function TypeError: info.backend.decComplexRef is not a function
at Engine.disposeTensor (https://h5c2h5-3000.csb.app/static/js/bundle.js:30676:22) 
at Tensor.dispose (https://h5c2h5-3000.csb.app/static/js/bundle.js:75130:19)
at Engine.endScope (https://h5c2h5-3000.csb.app/static/js/bundle.js:30873:18) 
at https://h5c2h5-3000.csb.app/static/js/bundle.js:30240:23 
at t.<anonymous> (https://h5c2h5-3000.csb.app/static/js/bundle.js:16772:92) 
at https://h5c2h5-3000.csb.app/static/js/bundle.js:16024:17 
at Object.next (https://h5c2h5-3000.csb.app/static/js/bundle.js:16035:8)
at Engine.scopedRun (https://h5c2h5-3000.csb.app/static/js/bundle.js:30258:9) 
at Engine.tidy (https://h5c2h5-3000.csb.app/static/js/bundle.js:30237:19) 
at tidy (https://h5c2h5-3000.csb.app/static/js/bundle.js:31746:54)
```

Here is the App.js file:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { OrbitControls } from "@react-three/drei";
import { Sky } from "@react-three/drei";
import { Physics, useBox, usePlane } from "@react-three/cannon";
import Webcam from "react-webcam";
import * as facemesh from "@tensorflow-models/facemesh";
import * as tf from "@tensorflow/tfjs";

export default function App() {
  const webcamref = useRef(null);
  const boxPosition = [0, 2, 0];
  const spotlightPosition = [
    boxPosition[0] + 3,
    boxPosition[1] + 5,
    boxPosition[2],
  ];

  const runFacemesh = async () => {
    const net = await facemesh.load({
      inputResolution: { width: 640, height: 480 },
      scale: 0.8,
    });
    setInterval(() => {
      detect(net);
    }, 100);
  };

  const detect = async (net) => {
    if (
      typeof webcamref.current !== "undefined" &&
      webcamref.current !== null &&
      webcamref.current.video.readyState === 4
    ) {
      const video = webcamref.current.video;
      const faces = await net.estimateFaces(video);

      if (faces && faces.length > 0) {
        const face = faces[0];
        const rotationY = face.annotations.midwayBetweenEyes[0][0];
        const rotationX = face.annotations.midwayBetweenEyes[0][1];
      }
      console.log(faces);
    } else {
      console.log(webcamref.current.video.readyState);
    }
  };

  const Box = () => {
    const [ref, api] = useBox(() => ({ mass: 1, position: boxPosition }));
    return (
      <mesh ref={ref}>
        <boxGeometry args={[1, 1, 1]} />
        <meshStandardMaterial color="hotpink" />
      </mesh>
    );
  };

  const Plane = () => {
    const [ref] = usePlane(() => ({
      position: [0, 0, 0],
      rotation: [-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0],
    }));
    return (
      <mesh position={[0, 0, 0]} rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]}>
        <planeGeometry attach="geometry" args={[100, 100]} />
        <meshLambertMaterial attach="material" color="brown" />
      </mesh>
    );
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    tf.setBackend("webgl");
    console.log(tf.getBackend());
    runFacemesh();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div style={{ width: "100vw", height: "100vh" }}>
      <Webcam
        ref={webcamref}
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          marginLeft: "auto",
          marginRight: "auto",
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          width: 640,
          height: 480,
          zIndex: -1,
        }}
      />
      <Canvas >
        <OrbitControls />
        <Sky />
        <ambientLight intensity={1.5} />
        <spotLight
          position={spotlightPosition}
          angle={0.3}
          penumbra={1}
          intensity={10}
          castShadow
        />
        <Physics>
          <Box />
          <Plane />
        </Physics>
      </Canvas>
    </div>
  );
}
```

deps in package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-three/cannon": "^6.5.2",
    "@react-three/drei": "^9.80.2",
    "@react-three/fiber": "^8.13.6",
    "@tensorflow-models/facemesh": "^0.0.5",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs": "^4.10.0",
    "loader-utils": "3.2.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-webcam": "^7.1.1",
    "three": "^0.155.0",
  },
```

I tried changing the backend to cpu and wasm

```
tf.setBackend("cpu")
```

```
tf.setBackend("wasm")
```

But that also doesn't seems to work